# Task already scheduled or cancelled

Tags: java, timer, timertask

recently I create a function `printName(String s)` including class `Timer` and class `TimerTask`.However, when I use this function continuously, it shows this error:

```java
a
Exception in thread "Timer-1" Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
a
    at ProxyPattern.TimerTest$1.run(TimerTest.java:21)
a
c
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
c
c
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
c
java.lang.NullPointerException
c
    at ProxyPattern.TimerTest$1.run(TimerTest.java:21)
b
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
b
b
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
b
b
a
a
```

this is my code:

```java
public class TimerTest {
    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;

    public void printName(String s) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
                timerTask.cancel();
                timerTask = null;
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimerTest timerTest = new TimerTest();
        timerTest.printName("a");
        timerTest.printName("b");
        timerTest.printName("c");
    }
}
```

I hope that it print 'a' five times, and then print 'b' five times, finally print ‘b’ five times. Just like this:

```
a
a
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
b
c
c
c
c
c
```

how to fix it?

Comment: You have contention on your `timerTask` variable. The `Timer` may execute `TimerTask`s in more than one thread. When you set `timerTask = null`, this may occur in one thread, while another is just about to call `timerTask.cancel()`.

Comment: @NotaJD I know what you said, but I don't know how to fix it, could u give me some idea??